# why excel process stay opened after printing

Tags: python-3.7, openpyxl, pywin32

i use these packages:
openpyxl - copy excel templates, opened copied file, save data from db, print it and then delete;
pywin32 - send for printing to remote network printer by network name;

after some processes, i don't know which - excel process window still opened. (attach screenshot)[image: open empty excel window]

i attach the most using in my project functions.
this program it's like a web service, which listening 5000 port and print in needed template.
i delete all created files, because of no need to store all of them.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os
import app_config as config
import printers.printers as p
from datetime import datetime
import shutil
import time


class EditExcelTemplate:
    def __init__(self, template_name):
        now = datetime.now()
        report_name = "_{}{}{}_{}{}{}_{}".format(now.year, now.month, now.day,
                                              now.hour, now.minute, now.second,
                                              now.microsecond)
        self.report_path = config.EXCEL_REPORT_PATH.format(template_name +
                                                           report_name)

        shutil.copy(src=config.EXCEL_TEMPLATE_PATH.format(template_name),
                    dst=self.report_path)

        # self.wb = load_workbook(filename=config.EXCEL_TEMPLATE_PATH.format(template_name))
        start_load = time.time()
        self.wb = load_workbook(filename=self.report_path,
                                keep_links=False,
                                keep_vba=False,
                                data_only=True)
        end_load = time.time()
        print('LOAD WORKBOOK|{}'.format(str(end_load - start_load)))
        self.ws = self.wb.active
        self.answer = {'file_name': template_name.upper()}

    def write_workbook(self, row_dest, column_dest, value):
        c = self.ws.cell(row=row_dest, column=column_dest)
        c.value = value


    def save_excel(self):
        self.wb.save(self.report_path)

    def print_excel(self, printer_no):
        p.print_excel(printer_no=printer_no, path_to_file=self.report_path)

    def print_excel_file(self, printer_name):
        p.print_excel_file(printer_name=printer_name, path_to_file=self.report_path)
```

```
import win32api
import app_config
import os, time


def print_excel(printer_no, path_to_file):
    printer_name = app_config.PRINTER_NAMES[printer_no]

    win32api.ShellExecute(
        1,
        'printto',
        path_to_file,
        '{}'.format(printer_name),
        '.',
        0
    )


def delete_file(path_to_file, try_count=1):
    if os.path.exists(path=path_to_file):
        file_name = path_to_file.split('\\')[-1]
        while try_count < 60:
            try:
                os.remove(path_to_file)
                print('File {} deleted!'.format(file_name))
                break
            except PermissionError:
                print('Can not delete file {}. Hold {} sec.'.format(file_name, try_count))
                time.sleep(1.0)
                try_count += 1
```

Comment: I noticed you don't have any `wb.close()` which is for OpenPyXl. Maybe give that a try

Comment: @EricDuanmu, i really forgot about it, thanx for your answer!

Comment: @EricDuanmu didn't work. I added close() method into function save_excel

```
    def save_excel(self):
        self.wb.save(self.report_path)
        self.wb.close()
```